# Controlar transação do Dapper com SimpleCrud / Erro: Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper

bom dia pessoal, tudo bem?

preciso controlar a transação do Dapper usando o SimpleCrud.
Tenho uma aplicação em asp.net core usando Injeção de Dependência.

Vou postar partes do código apenas (removendo conversões de ViewModel para Model e validações) pra não ficar tão complexo.

mas em resumo, tenho o Service>Business>Repository>Base

o Service faz a integração dos Business quando é necessária a integração entre vários Business.

Na service

```
public async Task SaveAsync(CourseViewModel courseViewModel)
        {
            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                await this._courseBusiness.SaveAsync(courseViewModel);
                transaction.Complete();
            }


            }
    }
```

Na Business

```
    public async Task SaveAsync(CourseClassViewModel courseClassViewModel)
    {
           await this._courseClassRepository.InsertAsync(courseClassViewModel);
    }
```

Na Repository

```
public async Task<T> InsertOnDataBaseAsync(T entity)
{
    Tkey id =  await _dbConnection.InsertAsync<Tkey,T>(entity);
    entity.Id = id;            

    return entity;
}
```

Quando faço o controle com Scope, tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro "Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported"

Aparentemente o Scope não consegue controlar as transações dentro do SimpleCrud.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse caso, já vi exemplos funcionando, mas não tinha a separação de camadas.

No caso de trocar o SimpleCrud, tenho a situação de fazer anotações onde algumas colunas não são alteradas no Update, e o SimpleCrud tem a anotação "Dapper.IgnoreUpdate" que me ajuda nesse caso.

acho que é isso, se alguém puder me ajuda.

obrigado

Answer (score -2):

O SimpleCrud aceita o transaction como parâmetro nos métodos CUD, porém ela vem da _dbConnection, para controlar isso você precisará implementar o UnitOfWork Pattern, o mesmo centralizará as conexões e repositórios.

Segue o código de exemplo no github:

[DapperUnitOfWork](https://github.com/timschreiber/DapperUnitOfWork)

No exemplo o repositório implementa o dapper direto, porém você pode manter o SimpleCrud, passando apenas a mais a transaction nos métodos que precisam de transação.